# "Finally" or "Do Last" for LMAX Disruptor?

Tags: disruptor-pattern, lmax

I'm trying to write a wrapper for the LMAX disruptor, and I'm wondering if there is a mechanism to add an event handler that executes at the end of the disrupter's flow.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The disruptor being analogous to a queue, there is no 'end' really. It's not like finite streams in reactive programing.

The publisher would be in charge of flagging the last event (you could have a boolean field in the event class just for that). It's the "poison record" technique.

You would have a handler that only performs when the flag is true. That's all.